# How can I create a stream of data from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stream

I am looking for a way to produce stream of data from static data, eg. I want to create a source where each row of data will arrive after 10 ms. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Share your tries please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just iterate with a timer to wait, using `yield` to create a generator, I used `itertuples` but you can change how you iterate the data

```
import time
import pandas as pd

def yield_wait(frame, ms):
    for v in frame.itertuples():
        yield v
        time.sleep(ms / 1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inp = [{'c1': 10, 'c2': 100}, {'c1': 11, 'c2': 110}, {'c1': 12, 'c2': 120}]
    df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

    for v in yield_wait(df, 1000): # print every 1sec
        print(v)
```

Comment: Simple, yet effective. Thanks @azro